# relational comparison result unused error for for() loop in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, compiler-errors, cs50

I'm doing this [challenge](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/1/mario/less/) and I am using this for loop for the code.

```
for (y >= i; y--;)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
```

But I keep getting this error back

```
mario.c:57:20: error: relational comparison result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-comparison]
        for (y > i; y--;)
             ~~^~~
```

The only trick that worked was making a useless variable inside the for() condition, but that would be useless and just take up space. Only other fixes?

Comment: Format of a C `for` loop: `for (initializer ; condition ; end_of_each_loop_expression)`. Any of the expressions can be empty. You seem to have `for (condition ; end_of_each_loop_expression ; (empty))`. A condition used as an initializer, unless it has side-effects or has an assignment, does nothing, which is what your message is telling you.

Comment: Thumbs up for using `-Werror`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first part of a `for` is the initialization part, not the condition.  The condition is the second part.  You instead want:

```
for (; y >= i; y--)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (y >= i; y--;)
                |
```

should be

```
for (;y >= i; y--)
     |
```

as 1. comes the initialization and/or definition of the counter variable (which can be omitted as explained below), 2. the condition and 3. the in- or decrementation of the counter.

The initialization part can be omitted only **if** the counter variable, here `y`, is *declared* and *initialized* **before** the loop.